# Difference between 'treatise' and 'epistle'

Tags: word-choice, nouns, synonyms, epithets

I noticed that sometimes these two are used interchangeably, especially as  designations of older, Medieval written documents. I know that '**epistle**' is a letter, whereas '**treatise**' is a written work concerned with a specific subject; surely, they are not synonymous. But can they ever be mutually inclusive? 
Any information regarding these two words is appreciable.

Comment: A treatise can be published as a book or can be addressed - in a letter - to an individual or a company of individuals. In which case it will also be an epistle. Paul's epistle to the Roman church is a treatise. His epistle to Philemon is not, but is personal.

Answer (score 1):

In layman's terms an epistle is a 'letter'; whereas a treatise is essentially an 'argument in writing'. (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epistle) (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treatise)